# iphone Memory Leak NSDictonary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

i'm not very familiar with the memory management in Objective-C but i try my best. My App is crashing after some Minutes. With the help of Instruments i found many Leaks. Sometimes i just forgot to release objects or don't put it in the Autorelease Pool. But now i don't really know wheres the problem is in this method.
Instruments shows leaks in 3 Lines.

Thanks for the help.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)rowsFromTablePages {

NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT paid, creationdate, lastuseddate, image, background, backgroundid FROM Pages WHERE nsid=%i ORDER BY paid", _nsid];

sqlite3_stmt *statement;
NSMutableArray *allPages = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

  if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
      while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
          int paid = (int)sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
          char *creationdate = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
          char *lastuseddate = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
          NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 3) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 3)]; // Leak
          NSData *databg = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 4) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 4)]; // Leak
          int bgid = (int)sqlite3_column_int(statement, 5);

          NSDictionary *rowInArray = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:paid], @"PAID", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:creationdate], @"CREATIONDATE", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:lastuseddate], @"LASTUSEDDATE", [UIImage imageWithData:data], @"THUMBNAIL", [NSNumber numberWithInt:bgid], @"BGID", [UIImage imageWithData:databg], @"THUMBNAILBG", nil]; // Leak

          [allPages addObject:rowInArray];
      }
      sqlite3_finalize(statement);
  }
  return allPages;
}
```

In the same class Instruments shows a leak where this method is called.

```
- (void)reloadDataFromSQL {
    _dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self rowsFromTablePages]]; // Leak
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: @HMMurdoc which lines does it mark?

Comment: i write "// Leak" on the end of three lines

Comment: @HMMurdoc if you leave out the `NSDictionary *rowInArray =...` and the `[allPages addObject:rowInArray];` lines does the leak still persist?

Comment: i cant leave them out, because the TabelView wont load without the Array. I cant simulate it. Another idea?!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think Instruments points to the allocation of the leaked objects, not the actual leaking of the objects. Since you are returning those objects indirectly through `allPages`, couldn't be the leak anywhere else?

Comment: Instruments shows me in the "Extended Details" a Stack Trace where the leak does happen i think. The last method in this Stack shows me the point of the leaked object.

Comment: @albertamg Thanks for bringing me in the right direction. The leak wasn't in the place.

Comment: @HMMurdoc You are welcome :) Just for the record, that stack trace you mention is for a particular event (e.g. alloc, retain, etc) in the allocation history. Anyway, I'm glad you found your leak!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method `reloadDataFromSQL` you're allocating new memory to an instance of `NSMutableArray` without releasing anything.

Comment: Oh thats painful... I added '[_dataSource release];' in the first line '-(void)reloadDataFromSQL {...}'. The Leaks are gone. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

How many times are you running that while loop? My suspicion is that maybe the autorelease pool is getting overloaded and generating a memory error. Try declaring the variables outside the while loop and manually releasing them. Let me know how that works.

Comment: The Loop is running 3 times because i got 3 Lines in my Database. I'll try to declare the variables outside.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `+dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:` instead of `-dataWithBytes:length:`. This will make sure that the bytes aren't copied, which should stop the leak.

Comment: In +dataWithBytesNoCopy i can't use sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 3). Any Idea?

Comment: dataWithBytes needs a "const void*" and dataWithBytesNoCopy needs a "void *"

Comment: I don't understand how this would work to stop the leak, since NSData's byte copying does not create leaks in general. And since SQLite3 is supposed to the memory from `sqlite3_column_blob()` automatically, I think this would result in a double-free. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

try this if it works....
if(_dataSource)

{

_dataSource =[self rowsFromTablePages];

}

else 
{

_dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self rowsFromTablePages]]; // Leak

}

[self.tableView reloadData];